# Why is the Java version not updated in Android Studio still 1.8.0?

Tags: java, android-studio

C:\development\flutter> java -version

java version "11.0.17" 2022-10-18 LTS

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.17+10-LTS-269)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.17+10-LTS-269, mixed mode)

C:\development\flutter>javac -version
javac 11.0.17

C:\development\flutter>flutter doctor -v

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version
10.0.19043.2130], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 3.0.5 at C:\development\flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision f1875d570e (5 months ago), 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
• Engine revision e85ea0e79c
• Dart version 2.17.6
• DevTools version 2.12.2

Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
33.0.0-rc1)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-32, build-tools 33.0.0-rc1
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin version 51.0.1
• Dart plugin version 193.7547
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
• VS Code at C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.54.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
• Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64  
  • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.2130]
• Chrome (web)   • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 108.0.5359.73
• Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 107.0.1418.62

[√] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

**I changed JDK Location in android studio
JDK location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.17
but not updated**

Comment: Where exactly did you change the JDK version? Note, that there is a difference between the JRE which is used to run Android studio itself, and the one which is used for developing projects. Which one exactly did you change or want to change?

Comment: for developing projects

Comment: Let Android Studio use whatever Java version it wants for itself. I’d personally be wary of changing standard IDE packaging/behavior.

Comment: but When I run the project it shows an error that wants jdk 11